# How to generate both xlxs and ods - Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, ods

I'm building an application with spring-boot and Java 11 that has a requirement that asks to export a report in ods and xlsx.

I read that jasper reports can support this. But there's no documentation that actually says that might be possible.

I also thought of creating an implementation of a TemplateClass and implementing an xlsx exporter with apache poi and implementing an ods exporter with another lib.

Do you know a better way?

Comment: You can generate both formats (xlsx and ods) with *JasperReports*. For generating ods you should use `JROdsExporter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got me so far, with output to a Servlet OutputStream, but the files where often corrupt. Ods has built in support in recent Jasper e.g. I tried this in 6.18.1.

```
if (format.equals("xlsx")) {
        JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter(); // initialize exporter
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint)); // set compiled r
        SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration reportConfigXLS = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
        Map<String, String> dateFormats = new HashMap<String, String>();
        dateFormats.put("EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy", "ddd, mmm d, yyyy");
        reportConfigXLS.setFormatPatternsMap(dateFormats);
        reportConfigXLS.setIgnoreGraphics(true);
        reportConfigXLS.setOnePagePerSheet(true); // setup configuration
        reportConfigXLS.setDetectCellType(true);
        reportConfigXLS.setSheetNames(new String[]{"Active Patients"});
        exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfigXLS);
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new 
          SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
        exporter.exportReport();
} else if (format.equals("ods")) {
        JROdsExporter exporter = new JROdsExporter(); // initialize exporter
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint)); // set compiled r
        SimpleOdsExporterConfiguration reportConfigXLS = new SimpleOdsExporterConfiguration();
        exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfigXLS);
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
        exporter.exportReport();
}
byte[] binData = out.toByteArray();
OutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
out1.write(binData);
out1.close();
response.setContentLength(binData.length);
```